# Who supported the Targaryens during Robert's Rebellion?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In *A Game Of Thrones* (I think, it may be one of the later books), Robert's Rebellion is briefly recapped and it is said that when Robert won, he stripped lands from those who opposed his claim during the rebellion.

In addition, there was the epic battle at the Trident where Rhaegar was killed by Robert.

Does it ever address in the books who supported the Targaryens during the war?

We know that the Vale (House Arryn), the Riverlands (House Tully) and the North (House Stark) supported the Stormlands (House Baratheon) in the rebellion, so from the seven kingdoms there are only the Westerlands (House Lannister), Highgarden (House Tyrell) and Dorne (House Martell) remaining.

---

The rest here is not based on memory so let me know if it's incorrect.

From what I gathered, the Westerlands pretty much kept out of the war. They covertly supported the Throne (which is how Tywin managed to gain access to King's Landing when it was sacked), but I don't think they ever openly opposed the Rebellion in battle.

Dorne probably supported the Throne because Elia was married to Rhaegar at the time.

How about Highgarden? Was this ever addressed? Or did the Targaryens hire mercenaries (like the Golden Company or the Second Sons) to fight on their behalf?

It seems like 4 houses going up against 2 wouldn't be much of a battle. Obviously Robert won, but I assumed it was a close contest.

Were the lands that Robert stripped just Dragonstone and its supporting Houses from the Targaryens?

Comment: i don't know why this was downvoted. The question seems legit to me.

Comment: @yondaime008 both my answer and Shevliaskovic's answer were also downvoted... very odd.

Comment: @Daft Maybe Daenarys has a Sci-Fi SE account...

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford I reckon it's more of Joffrey move!

Comment: @Daft But..but.. I thought Joffrey died with the purple wedding and all... UNLESS ! OMG !

Comment: Upvoted all three. Solid question, solid answers. As the Hound would put it...well, you guys know what he would say.

Comment: To find out the definitive answer to this and more similar questions I suggest reading "The World of Ice & Fire: The Untold History of Westeros and the Game of Thrones". It is from George RR Martin and the folks who build and maintain westeros.org, and is really pretty good for a history book of a fantasy series :D

Comment: @Monty129 **** the king?

Comment: @randal'thor that's the one.

Comment: Note that "stripped lands" doesn't necessarily mean *all* lands. In reasonably similar European history, what usually happened was that you'd transfer some of the titles (and vassals) around, and possibly, replaced the ruling family with another family (or, more commonly, imprisoned the actual ruler, while letting his heirs keep the title). You couldn't just take the lands for yourself - that would be inefficient and rather offensive and threatening. So the rebels might have lost control over a port or a city, and some might have lost their heads, but their lands weren't transferred to Robert.

Comment: We do not need to go to the wiki to figure out about the 7 major houses. The Tyrells are clearly mentioned as supporting the Targaryens- They beseiged Storm's End, which was in Barantheon (Stannis) control. After the fall of King's landing, they gave up the siege and knelt to the new king.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the wiki page on [Robert's Rebellion](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert's_Rebellion), the major families of the Seven Kingdoms were divided as follows during the war:

**Rebels**:

- [House Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Baratheon)
- [House Stark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Stark)
- [House Arryn](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Arryn)
- [House Tully](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Tully)
- [House Greyjoy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Greyjoy) (late war)
- [House Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Lannister) (late war)

**Royalists**:

- [House Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Targaryen)
- [House Tyrell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Tyrell)
- [House Martell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Martell)
- [House Darry](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Darry)
- [House Ryger](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Ryger)
- [House Mooton](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Mooton)
- [House Goodbrook](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Goodbrook)
- [House Connington](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Connington)
- [House Cafferen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Cafferen)
- [House Fell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Fell)
- [House Grandison](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Grandison)
- [House Grafton](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Grafton)

Once the war was over, Robert more-or-less forgave everyone who allied with the Targaryans.

If you want a **really great explanation** of the events leading up to the Rebellion and who sided with who and why, you should watch / listen to this, it's really good and  voiced by the actors from the show :

Comment: This was a good and thorough answer, but it could possibly have been improved by saying which of the royalist Houses were vassals that went against their rebellious ruling Houses. I didn't know that until I read the link (which was very insightful). But that's just me :).

Comment: @Mike.C.Ford that's a good point, but I'm not sure if the Overlord info provided on each Houses's wiki page is representative of the House's allegiance _before or after_ the war.

Comment: @Daft does that video contain any show spoilers. More specifically up until S05E01.

Comment: @DickieBoy no none at all. It's the events preceding S01E01.

Comment: You forgot House Thorne. Goodly part of Night Watch leadership at the start of Book 1 ended on the wall because Robert won! There's even a funny scene, when Tyrion has dinner with them and it turns out Tywin wanted them all executed but Ned told Robert to send them to the wall instead.

Answer (score 18):

This is mentioned throughout the 5 books so far; not only the first one. The [Wikia](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert%27s_Rebellion) has a good list for the supporters of the Targaryens:

- House Tyrell
- House Martell
- House Darry ( A Game of Thrones, Chapter 28, Catelyn.)
- House Ryger ( A Game of Thrones, Chapter 28, Catelyn.)
- House Mooton (A Game of Thrones, Chapter 16, Eddard.)
- House Goodbrook (A Storm of Swords, Chapter 43, Arya.)
- House Connington ( [So Spake Martin](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1118/))
- House Cafferen ( A Storm of Swords, Chapter 54, Davos.)
- House Fell ( A Storm of Swords, Chapter 54, Davos.)
- House Grandison ( A Storm of Swords, Chapter 54, Davos.)
- House    Grafton (A Dance with Dragons, Chapter 9, Davos.)

<sub>In the parentheses, I include where in the books it was mentioned</sub>